# How can I plot a graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this code, the x-axis shows values from one to ten. But I want it to show y.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
y = np.array([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19, 20, 21, 22,21,24,25,26,27])
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x)
results_half = peak_widths(x, peaks, rel_height=0.5)
results_full = peak_widths(x, peaks, rel_height=1)

plt.plot(x)
#plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
#print(peaks)
plt.hlines(*results_half[1:], color="C2")
plt.hlines(*results_full[1:], color="C3")
#plt.savefig('jgn1', dpi=50)
plt.show()
```

How can I change the x-axis in this code?

Comment: Try `plt.plot(y,x)` instead of `plt.plot(x)`

Comment: @swatchai. This is wrong

Comment: How do you want your `y` values on your graph? On y-axis or x-axis, or what else. If you use `plt.plot(x)` (without specifying y-values) default y values are used, not your y.

Comment: Jabar, you might have noticed by now that it is not clear what you mean by "how can I change x-axis", and your reply "This is wrong" is also not very helpful. I suggest explaining in more detail what you think the graph should show. An image from another source or a freehand sketch would suffice if you have difficulties describing your aim. We are not here to guess what your intentions are. Furthermore, imports are part of the code and should be included.

Comment: And I just noticed that your x- and y-values differ in length. What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @swatchai. on x_axis